# JavaScript: asynchronously create instance and use it in different modules

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, module

I am building a small web chat. The service that I use for chat requires me to create a client on the frontend - which then I can use in order to communicate. Code looks like this:

```
import Client from 'some-chat-service'

async function connect() {
    const token = await getToken() // first need to get token from backend
    const client = await Client.create(token) // then we can create client instance
}
```

Now, the problem is that I cannot use the `client` anywhere else (in different files), because it is declared in `connect` function.

The workaround would look like this:

```
import Client from 'some-chat-service'

export let client;

async function connect() {
    const token = await getToken()
    client = await Client.create(token)
}
connect()
```

Now, we can use the client anywhere we want, but it looks very weird to me.

Do you know how to handle such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want to call `connect`? If the importing module should call it, then simply `return` the client from the function, if the exporting module should start the connection itself (like in your second snippet), then you should export a promise:

```
export const clientPromise = getToken().then(Client.create);
```

```
// or with async/await:
async function connect() {
    const token = await getToken()
    return Client.create(token)
}
export const clientPromise = connect()
```

In any case, the module that imports this will need to wait for the initialisation promise.

Comment: Good question! I think it should connect automatically, because it can be used in many modules. Got it! Ideally, I should return the client and then do, `export const client = connect()`? :) Thank you!

Comment: No, (without [top-level-await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)) you cannot immediately export the asynchronously-created client, you can only export a promise for it.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do (your async/await example). Thank you!